# Migrate returns (in /app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake, dbmigrate

I've push my app to Heroku however my database(Sqlite3) fails to migrate. I understand that heroku will automatically migrate as a PG. [ I don't have PG install].

I figured if something was wrong, I would of received an error prompt.

This is my result:

```
pc-name$ heroku rake db:migrate --trace
(in /app)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

Also when I try to create-

```
pc-name$ heroku rake db:create --trace
cwogwtvrpc already exists
    (in /app)
** Invoke db:create (first_time)
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:create
```

Comment: what's the problem? try heroku restart

Comment: Hey Mikhail,The problem is, the db isn't migrating. I tried heroku restart to no avail.

Comment: I destroyed the app, and created it again. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try destroying the app and creating it again :)